# Javascript replace what does this line replace

Tags: javascript, replace

Simple question for you guys.

What does this line replace?

```
.replace(/ /g,'+')
```

Comment: Though the answer below is quite correct, you can always test such things yourself in a shell, as demonstrated in the example. I highly recommend a web developer console in Firefox (e.g. Firebug) or ctrl-shift-J in Chrome; or if you are doing server-side javascript, just testing things out in the appropriate shell. Even typing javascript:alert("This is a test".replace(/ /g,'+')) in your URL and hitting enter will reveal the answer. =)

Comment: What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: I know the console. Just wanted to make sure I don't miss anything...

Comment: @PeeHaa: I'm asking which part of the above statement you don't understand? You know that `replace` is replacing something. I also assume that you figured out that something is replaced with `+`. So I assume you don' understand what `/ /g` is, is this correct?

Comment: As the question clearly states: yes I want to know what is getting replaced :P

Comment: Mmmh.... true :D Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replaces every real space with a plus character.

```
"Simple question for you guys.".replace(/ /g,'+');  // "Simple+question+for+you+guys."
```

Comment: g is a flag that means "global replace". Everything inside the /s is a regular expression.

Comment: Remember that `\s` is something else then ` ` (<-- a single whitespace). `\s` means every space character. For example this will return `false`: 
`/ /.test($("<div/>").html("&nbsp").text());` while this will return `true`: `/\s/.test($("<div/>").html("&nbsp").text())`

Answer (score 2):

Replace spaces with +'s - Looks like some primitive URL-encoding?

Comment: I found it in the StumbleUpon share code. What do you guys think: should I just url encode it in stead of this replace?